# Can I use Python Exceptions to handle the aftermath of SIGHUP signals for a daemon?

Tags: python, exception, signals, daemon

I'm writing a simple little file-syncing daemon in python to implement a synchronised file system between a primary and secondary machine. Most of the heavy lifting is done by rsync.

On the primary side it periodically calls rsync and sleeps for a few seconds before repeating. On the secondary side it spawns rsyncd with subprocess.Popen() and does a .wait() until it exits. However I want to trigger a reconfiguration of the daemon with a SIGHUP. I'm wondering what the best way of handling clean-up is.

My initial thoughts were to have the signal handler raise an exception that can trigger the clean-up:

```
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise fsync_config_exception
```

And:

```
rsync_args = [rsync_binary, "--daemon", "--no-detach", "--config=%s" % (config.name) ]
p = subprocess.Popen(rsync_args)
try:
    p.wait()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        print "failed to spawn rsyncd"
        return False
except fsync_config_exception:
    print "spawn_and_monitor_rsyncd: config exceptions"
except:
    (type, value, tb) = sys.exc_info()
    print "we got %s with %s instead" % (type, value)
```

However I get a:

```
we got <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> with __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) instead
```

instead of the expected fsync_config_exception. Has anyone any suggestions for the best approach to this sort of problem? I'm I hideously abusing Exceptions by trying to raise them from a signal context?

Comment: Sorry for asking but wouldn't p.communicate() be better?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should raise a `fsync_config_exception` instance, not the class.  (Instantiate it using its `__init__()` signature)

However, I do not suggest raising asynchronous exceptions in that manner.  You'll have a hard time guaranteeing that the exception is only raised when it can be properly handled.  It's also not a good pattern to become accustomed to since you cannot interrupt blocking C extension calls in the Python interpreter context....(but that might not be a problem for you?)

In the signal handler, I would (glossing over details and not knowing if this is correct for your case):

- Set state noting that the current iteration has been interrupted - use this for marking if special cleanup is in order
- In the signal handler, kill the process that you're waiting on
- Add another condition check after the wait to see if the process was killed by a signal (with additional check on the state variable noting if the SIGHUP was received)
- Do what you need to do in response to the SIGHUP

Comment: The daemon is fairly simple (~200 lines) and doesn't call any C extensions. However I concur the abuse of Exceptions didn't help make it cleaner. In the end I just ended up making the process a global and wrapping a try/except around the kill in the signal handler to handle the race if the process dies before the signal arrives.